# JQuery UI Asp.net 4

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, dialog

I am working with JQueryUI and Asp.net and encounter a dynamic content problem:

```
<div id="content" title="" style="color: #F7A356"> 
<%=ContentLabel.Text%>
</div>

    function OpenDialog() {

   // alert(document.getElementById("content").innerHTML);

        var $dialog = $('<div style="color: #F7A356"></div>')
            .html($("#content").text())
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                height: 150,
            });


            $dialog.dialog('open');

    }
```

I would like to open a dialog when I click on a control and show the content..
but it failed with the above method....

it doesn't work even I just some a simple javascript alert function with the innerHTML.....It return nothing as well

Answer (score 1):

this is how it should look like..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      .dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
         modal: true,
         height: 150,
     });

       $('a .opendialog').click(function(){
           $('#content').dialog('open');
       }
    });
```

if this does not help please provide more html

Comment: watch that it should be `$('#content')` and not `$('.content')`

Answer (score 0):

You should add the newly created element to the document before opening the dialog. Try something like:

```
$('<div style="color: #F7A356"></div>')
    .html($("#content").html())
    .appendTo("body")
    .dialog({
        modal: true,
        height: 150
    });
```

Comment: I had tried this method. but it doesn't work... the function .html() return "" (nothing). But if I initially put some text inside the <div></div>, the function .html() can get them out. but if I use <%= [an asp.net control .Text] %> it return nothing